# `customer_save_after` event is not working in admin side

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, adminhtml, event-observer

I have a custom module which is used to observe for `cusotmer_save_after` event in admin side. I have added a custom tab `profile at glance` in Magento's customer module. I am using my module to store data that is collected through this custom tab in my custom table `customer_customization`.

My XML file is in `app/code/local/Electronicsstore/Customization/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Electronicsstore_Customization>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Electronicsstore_Customization>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customization>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Electronicsstore_Customization</module>
                <frontName>customization</frontName>
            </args>
        </customization>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <customization>
                <file>customization.xml</file>
            </customization>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <customization>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Electronicsstore_Customization</module>
                <frontName>customization</frontName>
            </args>
        </customization>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <customization>
                <file>customization.xml</file>
            </customization>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <electronicsstore_customization>
                    <type>model</type>                           
           <class>electronicsstore_customization_model_observer</class>
                    <method>saveCustomerCustomizationData</method>
                </electronicsstore_customization>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
    </events>

</adminhtml>

<global>
    <models>
        <customization>
            <class>Electronicsstore_Customization_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>customization_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </customization>
        <customization_mysql4>
            <class>Electronicsstore_Customization_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <customization>
                    <table>customer_customization</table>
                </customization>                    
            </entities>
        </customization_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <customization_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Electronicsstore_Customization</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </customization_setup>
        <customization_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </customization_write>
        <customization_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </customizations_read>
    </resources>

    <helpers>
        <customization>
            <class>Electronicsstore_Customization_Helper</class>
        </customization>
    </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

My model observer file looks like this.
`app/code/local/Electronicsstore/Customization/model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Electronicsstore_Customization_Model_Observer
{

/**
 * This method will run when the customer is saved from the Magento Admin
 * Use this function to update the customer model, process the
 * data or anything you like
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function saveCustomerCustomizationData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
     echo "i am here";die();


        try {
           // do some model loads and checks here so that you will update existing data and not duplicate rows on editAction saves...\
            $frontendModel = Mage::getModel( 'customization/customization' );
            $frontendCollection=$frontendModel->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => $object->getCustomerId()))->getFirstItem();
            if(!$frontendCollection->isEmpty())
            {

                $frontendCollection->addData($object->getData())->save();
            }
            else
            {
                //$frontendModel->addData('customization_parent_id',$object->getId())->save();
                $frontendModel->setData($object->getData());
                $frontendModel->setData("parent_id",$object->getId());
                $frontendModel->save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

}
```

**Note:** *die()* is not working while saving customer data.

However, my observer seems to be not working. I don't know what it causes. Please help me to find out the problems with my code. This is the first time I am dealing with an observer in Magento. So suggest me the best practice while dealing with observers

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think...'events' tag should be declared in 'global' tag not 'adminhtml' tag

Comment: `events` tag can come inside `global` node, `adminhtml` node and in `frontend` node. Where should it put depends upon the coditions that we need to achieve :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `adminhtml_customer_save_after` is correct event take a look in `\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\CustomerController.php`.

`customer_save_after` it is a different event for frontend.

But your class definition is wrong. Try this

```
<events>
    <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
        <observers>
            <electronicsstore_customization>
                <type>model</type>                           
                    <class>customization/observer</class>
                    <method>saveCustomerCustomizationData</method>
            </electronicsstore_customization>
        </observers>
    </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
</events>
```

Also do not forget to clear cache.

Comment: thanks for reply. But I have already tried this class also. It didnt worked.. I have copied your code and tried. no result. I think both the class definitions are same and should work. but for me, both of them not working

Comment: Answer updated. Can you try code again.

Comment: nope friend its not working. I have tried your code. Is there any other files necessary along with these two files in admin module?

Comment: Have you defined extension initialisation xml file in app/etc/modules?

Comment: oh yes and this module is seems to be enable when look into `system -> configuration` _advanced_ tab

Comment: Sorry I don't see anything wrong. Try to repeat all advises and clear cache once again.

Comment: ok...what about type.is `type` has any relevance here?

Comment: You can remove it.

Comment: You can try to change <class>customization/observer</class> to <class>Electronicsstore_Customization_Model_Observer</class>. But, all in all, it looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

You declared your event observer like this:

```
<events>
    <adminhtml_customer_save_after> <!-- this is wrong-->
        <observers>
            <electronicsstore_customization>
                <type>model</type>                           
       <class>electronicsstore_customization_model_observer</class>
                <method>saveCustomerCustomizationData</method>
            </electronicsstore_customization>
        </observers>
    </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
</events>
```

The event name is wrong (tag right under `<events>`). It should be the exact name of the event you are observing. In this case `customer_save_after`

Comment: :nope its not working. I have tried 'cutomer_save_after' first. But it didnt work. thats why i have used above observer. I have changed it to `customer_save_after` now and tried again. didnt work. Any other details of module is needed?

Comment: make sure you cleared the cache.

Comment: nope i have cleared and made a try twice. still no output. it confuses me. Is there is anything I miss in configuration?