# How to automatically add customers to customer group based on admin that added them

Tags: admin, customer-segmentation

I need to make happen following:

- I have five admins that can only access "Customer" area
- They are adding customers to buy in the front end
- Customers are divided into five groups

I need to make the process of adding users so it excludes choosing to which group customer is added but it needs to be added automatically based on which admin is adding the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom module with an observer for `adminhtml_customer_save_after`

In config.xml

```
<events>
    <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
        <observers>
            <magepal_admincustomergroup>
                <type>model</type>                           
                    <class>admincustomergroup/observer</class>
                    <method>saveAdminCustomerGroup</method>
            </magepal_admincustomergroup>
        </observers>
    </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
</events>
```

In your observer

```
public function saveAdminCustomerGroup(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

    $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId();

    //check current admin user info and set customer group
    // $customer->setData( 'group_id', 5 ); 
    // save customer

    // may want to check if customer already assign to a group
}
```

Comment: How can I tell it which admin is adding user to which group?

Comment: `$user->getUser()` contain all the admin user info... see http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-admin-user-id-name-username-email-etc/

Answer (score 0):

Yo can create an observer for the event `adminhtml_customer_save_after`, see the logged user and act consequently.

Comment: Please be more specific and elaborate, I'm not so advanced with Magento platform.

Comment: The entire process you want to follow without your custom logic is here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15155/customer-save-after-event-is-not-working-in-admin-side

Comment: Link is not helping me at all... I'm just trying to understand that if there is a way to disable the selection of customer groups when adding the customer and make that customer part of group based on the admin adding the customer..

Comment: Like if one admin is named "manager1" it adds to corresponding group automatically.

Comment: There is no way to do what you want without a pretty extensive knowledge in Magento since its not a core feature and as far as i saw, there is no extension for this. The links so far have everything you need but you also will need to fully understand how Magento works in order to accomplish what you need.