# Give a percentage off to everyone that has a specific email address. ie. employee@mywebsite.com

Tags: event-observer, customer-group

So anyone with our email address **@mywebsite.com** gets put into a group with a certain **amount off**.

They would still have to register. I know this can be done but I'm not sure how.

Can someone please assist me with this task?

I feel like the only way to accomplish this is by writing and event / Observer method to look for these events `customer_save_before` or `customer_save_before`.

Then the Observer would just assign them to a group number ID like 5 or whatever it may be.

Comment: Please specify magento version

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal Magento ver. 1.14.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can add customers with specific email addresses to Customer Group,
 lets call it **(mywebsite.com Group)**. Then using Shopping Cart Rules, create a discount rule that will only apply to customers that are in **mywebsite.com Group.**

Adding customers to Customer group is a manual job, but you can automate by writing an extension. Might be worth it if you have a large influx of potential clients with "@mywebsite.com" that you cannot handle manually.

This topic describes a way you can automate customer group assignment
[How to automatically add customers to customer group based on admin that added them](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31718/how-to-automatically-add-customers-to-customer-group-based-on-admin-that-added-t)