# Customer after save event not triggered if admin add a customer

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, event-observer

I would like to trigger an event when admin add a new customer, I created a new module under local code pool. It is listed in admin->system->configuration->advanced also.

But after save event is not triggered.

Below is my code:

config.xml

```
 <config>
   <global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <customer_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <My_WebService_customer_register_success>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>My_WebService_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                    </My_WebService_customer_register_success>
                </observers>
            </customer_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
   </global>
 </config>
```

Observer.php

```
<?php
class My_Module_Model_Observer {
    public function customerRegisterSuccess() {
        Mage::log('I came inside', null, 'beta_version.log');
    }
}
?>
```

When no log created I checked my log settings enabled or not, it is enabled also. But event not triggered,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `adminhtml_customer_save_after` event for admin customer creation.

i.e.,

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <My_WebService_customer_register_success>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>My_WebService_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                    </My_WebService_customer_register_success>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

[Check this code](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php#l363-l366)

### Edit :

You have to call the event inside the `adminhtml` not inside `global`

Comment: Yes, i referred http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15155/customer-save-after-event-is-not-working-in-admin-side which is similar to this, but no luck :-( there is no error log captured also

Comment: @version.beta remove `global` tag from the config.xml

Comment: I will give a try but events should be written in side global right? Am I wrong?

Comment: Check this http://prattski.com/2010/08/30/magento-event-observer-scope/ . You'll get better understanding about the scope

Comment: what is the need of observe and drawback of non observe?

Comment: if we use observers, we dont want to rewrite the core files

Comment: you can just google. Anyway this is the better tutorial for core rewrite http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: I am aware of how to re write. My doubt is if it is observe we need not to rewrite core module. what will be the scenario we need to rewrite to core module if observe not happening? One example scenario